# Passing String/XML request to a http outbound as text/xml

Tags: xml, mule

I have a scenario where I need to call a web-service via a http:outbound. The service accepts only text/xml.

But after my transformations and conversions I get my payload(xml) as byte[]  or a String. 
When this payload is passed a request to the service via http:outbound it is coming back with error saying

```
Exception stack is:
1. Message contained MIME type "application/atom+xml" when "text/xml" was expected.     
Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
```

Given below is part of my flow.

```
<mule-xml:xslt-transformer
        maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"
        xsl-file="C:\EWS\MyProject\src\main\resources\xslt\XML_Repeater.xsl">
</mule-xml:xslt-transformer>

 <!-- <byte-array-to-string-transformer></byte-array-to-string-transformer>  -->

 <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" mimeType="text/xml"  
        address="http://sampleproj:9080/myservice/servlet/rpcrouter" />
```

How can I pass the expected mime-type to the http:outbound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
```

right before the `http:outbound-endpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to set mime-types but did you try using `<cxf:proxy-client>` to send the soap request something like shown below. Also, you might need to specify `SoapAction` to specify which operation to call on web-servicve

```
<mule-xml:xslt-transformer
    maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"
    xsl-file="C:\EWS\MyProject\src\main\resources\xslt\XML_Repeater.xsl">
</mule-xml:xslt-transformer>
<set-property propertyName="SOAPAction" value="http://operationToCall" />
<cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
   <cxf:outInterceptors>
     <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
   </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:proxy-client>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" mimeType="text/xml"  
    address="http://sampleproj:9080/myservice/servlet/rpcrouter" />
```